# Can't run very first tracking.js example on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, tracking.js

I'm trying to get familiar with tracking.js, but when I try to run the very same example given on the project's page (http://trackingjs.com/docs.html#introduction), nothing happens.
Google-chrome doesn't even shows the prompt asking if I want to allow the page to access to my webcam. The same thing happens for Firefox.

I have already ran the other examples from the tracking.js-master/ package, and the only one that fails is the one described on the tutorial, which I've added.

Below is the code which I copied and pasted from the tracking.js intro page to my first_tracking.html file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>tracking.js - first tracking</title>
  <script src="../build/tracking-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This shows in the browser</p>
  <video id="myVideo" width="400" height="300" preload autoplay loop muted></video>
  <script>
  var colors = new tracking.ColorTracker(['magenta', 'cyan', 'yellow']);

  colors.on('track', function(event) {
      if (event.data.length === 0) {
      // No colors were detected in this frame.
      } else {
      event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
        console.log(rect.x, rect.y, rect.height, rect.width, rect.color);
        });
      }
      });

  tracking.track('#myVideo', colors);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone tried and succeeded in running the introduction examples listed on the tracking.js page and have any pointers?

Research: Most of the stuff found on a google search relate to Google Analytics, Node.js and other JS  frameworks. I also found some people suggesting setting the *preload* option to *auto*, resulting in *preload="auto"*, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the example working with the webcam. Here's how.

First, Go into to root tracking.js directory and start a simple server. If you have python installed, try running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, then visit `http://localhost:8000/examples/first_tracking.html` to see your example, assuming your file is located in the examples directory of the unzipped file. **This is important**. If you just open the file in your browser, you will get an error: [Canvas tainted by cross-origin data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674835/canvas-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)

Save the following code to first_tracking.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>tracking.js - first tracking</title>
  <script src="../build/tracking-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="myVideo" width="400" height="300" preload autoplay loop muted></video>
<script>
var colors = new tracking.ColorTracker(['magenta', 'cyan', 'yellow']);

colors.on('track', function(event) {
  if (event.data.length === 0) {
    // No colors were detected in this frame.
  } else {
    event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
      console.log(rect.x, rect.y, rect.height, rect.width, rect.color);
    });
  }
});

window.onload = function() {
  // note here that 'camera' is set to true, I believe this tells tracking.js to use
  // the webcam.
  tracking.track('#myVideo', colors, {camera: true});  
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure your server is still running, then visit `http://localhost:8000/examples/first_tracking.html` and inspect the console. You should see output like the following

`260 47 37 47 "cyan" first_tracking.html:18`

Comment: Hey Julia, thanks for answering. I do have a webcam and I also had apache running. I was able to see the actual video frame on the code inspector, but still the page was empty. I tried your suggestion of using python's SimpleHTTPServer and replaced the video with the image tag. I was able to see the image, but on the code inspector I got: 
"Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0. tracking-min.js:8
tracking.trackCanvasInternal_ tracking-min.js:8
(anonymous function) tracking-min.js:8
s.onload"

Comment: Hi Vinicius, the error you are getting is because the `tracking.track` code is being executed before the image has fully loaded. is the code `tracking.track(...);` in the `window.onload` function? All code inside `window.onload` will be executed after all resources are loaded on the page. I was able to reproduce your error by moving `tracking.track` outside of the `window.onload` function.

Comment: Hi Julia, I double checked and made sure `tracking.track(...)` is being called from within the `window.onload` function. This is what the code looks like: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4111ff316c529a6ea56e, and it still fails.
Thanks for your help btw. =)

Comment: I think I'm having a similar issue to @ViniciusSilva - the examples work fine, until I make a change or rename the file. I wonder if it's an encoding issue...

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this problem myself and the issue for me was a missing parameter to the tracking.track() call...

The example online shows this:

```
tracking.track('#myVideo', colors);
```

When it should be this:

```
tracking.track('#myVideo', colors, { camera: true });
```

Technically Julia's post includes this param so I'm ok with that as the accepted answer, but just in case someone else runs into this problem, this is what fixed it for me.  With the camera flag, I was able to run the example without waiting for dom load as well, if that matters for anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

`{ camera: true }` is missing from the example code. As previous answers mention, include `tracking.track('#myVideo', colors, { camera: true });`