# Cannot load data to canvas once the Content Security policy added in aspx application

Tags: javascript

When Content security policy got added in my aspx application my Signature pad got stopped working on loading an existing Sign and working fine when creating a new sign

Added this in Web.config.

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy"  value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the data you're trying to load onto the canvas comes from another domain, and in your JS console, you get [this `canvas has been tainted by
cross-origin data` error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674835/canvas-tainted-by-cross-origin-data)?

Answer (score 0):

When reloading the aspx page we need to initialize the canvas with the  Signature pad 2nd time. This won't be the case with a SPA as loading of page will happen only once.