# fullscreen images on click ionic4

Tags: html, ionic4

I'm looking to make a live go fullscreen when I click on it, but I did not succeed to find any tutorial that matches my specific case...
I tried to use javascript but did not succeed :/
so my home.page.ts is empty,
but here is my HTML code:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
          <button >
          <ion-card color="dark" >
              <ion-card-header>
                  <b>Parking</b>
              </ion-card-header>     
              <ion-card-content>
                  <img id="img" width="250" height="160" src="http://131.173.8.23:80/mjpg/video.mjpg"/>
              </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
          </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
          <button>
          <ion-card color="dark">
              <ion-card-header>
                  <b>Hall</b>
              </ion-card-header>     
              <ion-card-content>
                  <img width="250" height="160" src="http://131.95.3.162:80/mjpg/video.mjpg"/>
              </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
            </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
          <button>
          <ion-card color="dark">
              <ion-card-header>
                  <b>Accueil</b>
              </ion-card-header>     
              <ion-card-content>
                  <img width="250" height="160" src="http://84.87.238.54:80/SnapshotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&amp;Quality=Clarity&amp;0"/>
              </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
            </button>
      </ion-col>          
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: you're gonna need js to do that.
I think you need to add and remove a css class on your images with each click

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display an image full screen when clicked you can use the ionic plugin [Photo Viewer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-viewer). It also adds the ability to pan, zoom, and share the image.

Comment: hi ! thank you for your answer ! 
unfortunately i tried this plugin and since i'm willing to use .mjpg files it dosent fit :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I hope it will helps you.

HTML:

```
  <ion-content>
    <div class="ion-padding">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <button>
          <ion-card color="dark">
            <ion-card-header>
              <b>Parking</b>
            </ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-content>
              <img id="img" width="250" height="160"
                src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
                (click)="clickImage('https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500')" />
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
        </button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                <button>
          <ion-card color="dark">
            <ion-card-header>
              <b>Accueil</b>
            </ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-content>
              <img width="250" height="160"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541233349642-6e425fe6190e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80://84.87.238.54:80/SnapshotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&amp;Quality=Clarity&amp;0"
                (click)="clickImage('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541233349642-6e425fe6190e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80://84.87.238.54:80/SnapshotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&amp;Quality=Clarity&amp;0')" />
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
        </button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PhotoViewer } from '@ionic-native/photo-viewer/ngx';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private photoViewer: PhotoViewer) {}

  clickImage(image){
    console.log("image clicked",image);
    this.photoViewer.show(image);
  }

}
```

Comment: hi ! thank you for your answer !
as i said a little bit higher, this plugin doesn't woked for me, i'm using .mjpg files, wich are a sequence of pictures, but not a video... so images viewers don't work, neither video players (at least i fdidn't find one)

Comment: then maybe try doing something on the canvas yourself. You can check this answer as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500558/motion-jpeg-in-html5-canvas